# ASMX service slow for certain users

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, asmx

We wrote a simple ASMX web service (something like hello world). And hosted it on another computer.

We have 3 computers in the same network from which we call the service. For one computer it takes 15-20ms to call the service, for two it takes 200-300ms.

I tried to write a tracelog on the server and in all 3 cases the full cycle from 
*Calling IHttpHandlerFactory.GetHandler*
to
*Return from IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest*
takes 10-15ms~.

Any suggestions how to debug the problem and what could be the case?

Comment: Have you looked at PerfMon or TaskMan on the slow computers?  The problem could be network bandwidth, but more likely it could be authentication or anti-virus adding delays.  I would need to know more about the slow machines and other stuff that your WS does, to give a better answer.

Comment: Yes, I did. However, I do not see anything suspicious there.
I tried to run Telerik Fiddler. With Telerik Fiddler capturing http traffic it takes 20ms~, if I turn Fiddler off then it is 200-300ms~.
I'm using HTTP 1.1 on all machines and Keep-Alive attribute is set to True.